# self host deployment of Sentry version 23.5.2, how to use external independent kafka, clickhouse, redis, postgres

Tags: docker-compose, sentry, self-hosting

When I need to self host deploy Sentry version 23.5.2 for production environment, I don't want all service components to be on the same machine. And I have an independent machine to deploy the components, so how to use external independent kafka, clickhouse, redis, postgres. Does anyone have experience how to modify the configuration file?

I want modify sentry configuration file。